# Persisting log4j settings with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, log4j

I have set up to use log4j with Spring using a log4j.xml file, and it works fine. I'm able to change the log level at run time using a controller which will eventually do this:

```
LogManager.getLogger("logger1").setLevel(Level.toLevel(level));
```

However, I have no idea how to persist the settings to my log4j.xml file at shutdown.  Can I?  What are the options?

I'm new to Spring.  A nice simple example would be appreciated!

Comment: It works the other way around, you write you settings to the log file and they get picked up by log4j, your log settings don't get persisted

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can remember is to open the file and write it before shutdown. I will involve parsing the file and writing the desired properties.

Although keep in mind that you are subverting the common use and most of the times means you are trying to do something in a wrong way. Question yourself you really need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to, you could call `LoggerManager.getLoggerRepository()`, and then `getCurrentLoggers()` to get an `Enumeration`.  Then you traverse the enumeration, read off the relevant properties of each Logger, and save them somewhere.

But there a number of reasons why this is probably a bad idea.

- Unless you are clever about it, you will end up persisting lots of redundant information about loggers and levels that have not been overridden dynamically.
- The actual loggers that are used depends on the code, and is liable to change as the application evolves.  You could end up maintaining settings `Loggers` that are no longer used ... and creating them!
- If you persist the settings to a database using Hibernate (for example) you could have a "chicken and egg" problem.  Hibernate needs logging to be functional before it starts, but you need to fetch the settings from the database ... first.
- Your logging configurations may end up looking nothing like the original log4j config file, making it difficult to understand what is being logged and what not.
- If the code in your application that adjusts logging levels goes wrong, you could be stuck.
- It is just not how IT people expect logging to work.